# evaluate the sum of the following series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have tried for a long time on this:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

Even I have no idea whether it could be calculate or not

Comment: It is not hard to prove convergence. Would be pessimistic about explicit closed-form expression.

Comment: yes, it's easy to prove convergence. here is another tough problem I haven't solved:calculate the sum $\sum_{n\in S}\frac{1}{n}$, where $S=\{n|n\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } n \text{ has no digits } 9\}$, that is for example $9, 19, 92 \notin S$, $3,11,18\in S$

Comment: Does that even converge?

Comment: Apparently so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series

Comment: @user7530 Yes it does, because you can bound the single digit denominators by $8$, the 2-digit denominators by $\frac {8^2}{10}$, the 3-digit denominators by $\frac {8^3}{100}$ etc. However, calculating the convergence isn't easy, or known.

Comment: This series was a problem from the second day 2011 International Math Competition.  See here:  http://www.imc-math.org.uk/index.php?year=2011&item=problems

Comment: yes, that's right. I've find it, and this problem had lasted for such a long time.